# Learning LaTeX -- book promotions

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

**Update:** As requested by TeX friends, the [LaTeX Cookbook](http://bit.ly/1NGnDa3) promotion has been extended by 1 week, until October, 31, there's a new 35% discount code: SVLIDA7. This time for *printbook and ebook* because printbook was user requested but at first the publisher only allowed ebook discount.

---

When I recently made my LaTeX Guide available for free download for one day (see [blog post](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2015/03/latex-beginners-guide-available-for-download-today/)), with permission of my publisher, some users had missed that occasion.

So I'm happy to say that the publisher agreed with me to

- make a discount of 50% for a longer time for the [Beginner's Guide](http://bit.ly/1V5iQ7L) (applies until November 30th, 2015, use coupon code tDRet6Y, total number limited)
- <s>make a discount of 35% for pre-ordering the new [LaTeX Cookbook](http://bit.ly/1NGnDa3)</s> (valid until October 18th, 2015, use coupon code LXCB35)

I again wrote a [new blog post](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2015/09/latex-cookbook/) about it, no need to repeat that here. I just noticed, a blog post is hardly visible:

- not in the right side bar for some days, as it used to be earlier
- no mention of the blog post in the auto-generated TeX Stack Exchange newsletter.

So, before that occasion ends (in one week) I decided to mention it here on Meta. It's a valid place, since parts of the book are about this site, TeX Stack Exchange. How? I will write this as answer.

If you like the idea that TeX.SE members, who wrote a book and can offer it with a discount promotion, can tell it visibly our members, you could up vote the [Beginner's guide ad](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6343/213). With a minimum score of 6, it becomes visible from time to time (as there are many others with a lot higher score). I will delete both after promotion end.

If you consider it as undesirable promotion, independent if it's supporting publishing LaTeX books, you may downvote of course. But I hope a cookbook style one which is fully based on examples would be welcome. :-)

And in my answer you can see, that I made massive TeX Stack Exchange promotion in my books, mainly in the first one.

Finally, you can get a quick impression of the new book by visiting the gallery [LaTeX-Cookbook.net](http://latex-cookbook.net). I put a [sample chapter](http://latex-cookbook.net/articles/graphics/) there, and I am adding examples step by step.

Comment: I managed to get your Beginner's Guide when it was on sale, and it's *awesome*, so I can't wait to see what your cookbook has to offer!

Answer (score 19):

As I promised above, here are samples what my books are telling the world and specifically new TeX users about our site TeX.SE. I will post some pure screenshots.

[image: Intro]
[image: Starting TeX.SE]
[image: Using TeX.SE]
[image: About TeX Stack Exchange]